# Is a relation $R$ on a set $X$ a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, separation-axioms

I'm reading Set Theory by Thomas Jech.

> An n-ary relation $R$ is a set of $n$-tuples. $R$ is a relation on $X$ if $R \subset X^n$.

I tried to conclude that a relation $R$ on a set $X$ is a set using **Separation Schema**

> $$\forall X \forall p \exists Y \forall u (u \in Y \leftrightarrow u \in X \land \varphi(u, p))$$

Although it will be trivial when $X$ is a finite set(by enumerating each of the tuples), I think it's difficult to construct such a formula $\varphi(u,p)$ according to $R \subset X^n$ when $X$ is an infinite set.

Appreciate your help in advance, thanks.

Comment: Relations over $X$ are defined to be any subset of $X\times X$, and thus are by definition sets themselves.  $n$-ary relations are any subset of $X^n$, again by the very nature of the fact they are *subsets* must themselves be sets.  I think you are overcomplicating things.

Comment: $R$ is a subset of cartesian product $X \times X$; thus, you have to prove that the cartesian product of two sets is a set.

Comment: In general, for $A \times B$, if $u = \langle x,y \rangle = \{ \{ x \}, \{ x, y \} \}$ (following Kuratowski's def of *ordered pair*, see page 7) we have that $ \{ x \}, \{ x, y \} \in \mathcal P (A \cup B)$, and thus $u=\langle x,y \rangle \in \mathcal P(\mathcal P (A \cup B))$.

Comment: The definition *tells you* that $R$ is a set. There is nothing more to it than that.

Comment: Please, not first line page 10: "Using the Power Set Axiom we can define other basic notions of set theory."

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for your answer. It really corrected my wrong opinion.